# Not getting query output wen using if condition in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select field in my html form with values " Both,Purchase and Refund". when selecting the both option i need to execute

```
select * from mytable where type in('Purchase','Refund')
```

in the sql query. When i am selecting 'Purchase' or 'Refund' individually i am getting the correct output. But when selecting the 'Both' opting I am not getting any result. Please help... Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$fdate=$_POST['fromdt'];
$tdate=$_POST['todt'];
$type=$_POST['txnType'];

if($type ='Both')
{
    $type = 'Purchase'.','.'Refund';        
}
$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],
            "select * 
             from dlbcc_purchase 
             where purch_date between '$fdate' and '$tdate' 
             and txn_type in ('$type') 
             order by date(purch_date)desc")or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
```

Comment: String literals need to be quoted in your SQL statement... in an IN statement, they need to be individually quoted, so `IN ('Purchase,Refund')` is searching for an actual value of `'Purchase,Refund'` in txn_type.... `IN ('Purchase','Refund')` would search for either `Purchase` or `Refund`

Comment: I didn't post a reply. I was going to post a reply similar to jeroen, but he beat me to it.

Comment: @Barmar, the information provided by you is equal to replay for my question. :)

Comment: What information? All I did was fix your question formatting. Are you talking about @MarkBaker's comment?

Comment: @Barmar, when you stated " they need to be individually quoted, so IN ('Purchase,Refund') is searching for an actual value of 'Purchase,Refund' in txn_type" in your comment, I understand My mistakes is related to the quotes.

Comment: @PrajithAS I didn't write that. Mark Baker did.

Comment: @Barmar...... sorry sorry sorry.... its my mistake..... I saw "Barmar edited" , so i thought the comment provided by Barmar itself. I didnt check the name.

Comment: @Mark Baker, Sorry for misunderstanding and thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a prepared statement to prevent the sql injection problem you have now.

However, your current problem is caused by the quotes. When the query is built, your condition will look like:

```
... txn_type in ('Purchase,Refund') ...
```

So you are missing the quotes around the comma to delimit the values.

You can solve that using:

```
if($type ='Both')
{
  $type = "Purchase','Refund";
                   ^ ^ these quotes
}
```

Now the result will be:

```
... txn_type in ('Purchase','Refund') ...
```